# Null Object pattern and Enums

Tags: c#, enums, null-object-pattern

I have a class `Person` with an Enum for a property. It is a non-nullable Enum.
I have some new requirements and I can easily take care of them by introducing a Null Object `NullPerson` with all the properties set to `String.Empty`, however the `Enum` property cannot be left empty, it always defaults to the first value it has define for its type.

What are my options here? Should I:

1. Make the `Enum` property Nullable or
2. Introduce a new value for the `Enum`, something that would indicate it is not set: e.g. TypeEnum.None?

Option 1. requires me to do less changes to other code that depends on `Person` / `NullPerson`.

Comment: Depending wich one would be better for you?

Comment: I'm on the fence, wanted to get some feedback. Articles on Null Object have never touched upon the topic of Enums.

Comment: Both are reasonable. A `TypeEnum.None` does always make sense

Comment: Why do you need object `NullPerson`? Can't you just use `null` and handle that?

Comment: I would suggest adding a `None` option to the enum, but it's really more a personal preference than anything. making the enum nullable would potentially expose you to the risk of having a null reference exception. enums are value types, I would argue you should keep them that way.

Comment: @FCin to avoid using nulls in code.  See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12777/are-null-references-really-a-bad-thing

Comment: It would make the code less readable. And a `NullPerson` would fit well with the existing code, except for this Enum. It is a rather non-invasive way for me handle certain corner cases.

Comment: @Amy But if someone decides to use C# then they have to deal with pron and cons... This is going against the nature of the language.

Comment: @FCin Actually, there are talks of [(non)nullable reference types planned for c#...](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/11/15/nullable-reference-types-in-csharp/)

Comment: A null object only really works if existing code can handle this null object "naturally", otherwise you're no better off than with `null`, as both require sprinkling checks throughout the code. So if you can introduce a `None` member and existing code would handle this, then great. Making the enum nullable *just* to accommodate the null object makes it a weird "half null" object where you still have to introduce checks. Yet another possible option is to implement the property with a simple `InvalidOperationException` when accessed, if there *is* no sensible default behavior.

Comment: @FCin I didn't intend to discuss the merits of avoiding `null` in c# in these comments.  I was just answering your question and giving you a starting point for understanding why the OP might want to do this.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: great explanation. I can handle `NullPerson` naturally with my code. I want to avoid raising exceptions of any sort since a concrete response is expected even with faulty input data (this is a primitive search engine). Plus my repo is used all over the place and a new exception would require a significant amount of rework.

Comment: Incidentally, enum fields do not default to "the first value" if not initialized, they default to `0`. That's normally the `None` tag if it's explicitly defined, but if not, the enum still has the value `0` with no tag. That may or may not work for your code. A surprising amount of code fails in unhelpful ways if enums have "out-of-tag" values because it never considers the possibility when converting them, but you won't know until you check.

Comment: Re: `InvalidOperationException`: this should be used only if you know the code should never check the property at all in case of the null object (for example, because it will always bail out early). If it's always accessed, that's obviously not appropriate (and `InvalidOperationException` should never be caught explicitly).

Comment: @JeroenMostert "Incidentally, enum fields do not default to "the first value" if not initialized, they default to 0" - True, but by default (that is, unless specified otherwise), [the value of the first enum member is 0.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum)

Comment: @JeroenMostert: your incidental remark about Enums and 0's has allowed me to resolve my issue with minimal changes to the existing code. No need for an `Enum.None` at all, one new `Null Object` defined and a change to the repo so it returns a `Null Object` instance. If you write up all your comments into an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Pass; very hard to write up a good answer that covers the pros/cons properly. Your question would need to be more specific to show why it's the best choice in your case, and even then it's a bit too opinion-based. It's good that leaving the value at `0` worked for you; feel free to write up an answer yourself to that effect as to why, particularly. (I will freely admit that I may have too high a standard for answers. :-))